# Bill thought of the problem. vs. Bill thought about the problem

Tags: interpretation

> Bill thought of the problem carefully.

> Bill thought about the problem carefully.

Any difference could be?

Only difference is 'of' and 'about'. This means the answer is the difference between 'of' and 'about'.

> of : a friend of mine, the leg of the table, sth consist of sth, remind A of B give hint, i.e., 'of' needs precedent before of and object after of, which means 'of' provides connection between specific two things and narrows sth down to specific information: A of B. So "think of sth" means think of specific B, the existance of B

> about : about 10 mins gives hint, hid money about myself gives hint. about means scattered, i.e., not a fixed point. so 'think about X' means 'X' has some attrubutes around X and you think some of the attributes or the attributes.

Comment: As it stands the first one describes a very  unusual situation. Can you expand to give more context about when you would write it?

Comment: I just added some explanation lightly to the original question but hope to receive any answer if possible reinforcing my explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Thinking *of*" something can often imply a fleeting thought - something popping into one's mind momentarily, or perhaps repeatedly thinking about the same thing.

"Thinking *about" something implies thinking over the *details* of something, perhaps with a view to reaching a conclusion.

To my ears, as a native English speaker, "thinking of a problem" sounds like someone remembering that they have a problem, whereas "thinking *about* a problem" sounds like someone is thinking of possible *solutions* to it.

Comment: Agreed.  "Thinking of a problem" could also mean "coming up with", as in "Bill thought of a problem for his students to solve."

Comment: stangdon, yes, i agree to "coming up with" thanks for your comment.